# Google App Engine SDK for Python Not Installing on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I followed the directions from this page to download the Google App Engine SDK for Python, on Mac:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

I downloaded the zip file, copy pasted the commands into terminal, and yet there is no Google App Engine application installed. There is only the unzipped folder.

What to do?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. There used to be a GUI launcher that was poorly supported and which I found to be a confusing additional layer though it did guide the installation better. I replaced it with just the SDK but I am now realizing on both Linux and Mac it should be more clearly explained what to do with the zip. Top answer looks roughly right along with my comment,  please comment here again if you can't get things working and where you're stuck. Will try to improve the docs.

Answer (score 2):

If all you did was copy-paste the instructions, that's where you might have gone wrong, because of the paths.

Take this command for example, `unzip google_appengine_1.9.40.zip`

Normally on Mac, a file downlads to your 'Downloads' folder, so you need to be there, or reference to that specific location. To make sure you're getting it right..

1. Open a new terminal window
2. Type `cd` + Enter. This will get you to your root folder.
3. Now type `unzip ~/Downloads/google_app` and hit a tab, this will autocomplete your path, and you'll be sure you're doing it right.
4. Once it's autocompleted, hit Enter.

Up to this point all you have is an unzipped file, that should be in your root folder. Run the following command `ls`, and you should get in the outputs your `google_appengine` folder. If it does, we're good.

Once again, for the next step, we have the paths situation.. so in the next instruction of the tutorial, namely

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/google_appengine/
```

theres a `/path/to/`, you have to substitute this bit with the actual path. Since it's on your root folder, if you followed up to this point, type this in: `pwd` This outputs your root folder path.. Say it prints `/Users/mylaptop`
Then, the command you have to paste would look like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/mylaptop/google_appengine/
```

Now run the last instruction of the tutorial, although it's not necessarily related to this installation, but you do need python to use appengine.

Comment: In addition to this, make sure you add your final `export PATH` line to your ~/.bash_profile file so you don't have to do this every time.